# Steps of proof?

Tags: logic

I am learning about logical connectors in set theory class. One thing that I do not understand is steps of proof. Professor says that if P => Q is true and P is true then we can say that Q is true. I agree with the logic but how can we show that P => Q is true? To show that shouldn't we first show that Q is true?

Comment: To show $P\implies Q$, we start by assuming $P$ is true without proof and try to show $Q$ is true as well.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, can you give me any examples of the professor's logic of proof?

Comment: Here is an example. Lets show that $2\cdot 3$ is even rigorously. We will do so by showing that $2$ is even, then separately we will show that if $a$ is even, then $3a$ is even. The definition of even I will use is: $a$ is even iff $a=2k$ for some integer $k$. First, $2=2(1)$ so $2$ is even. Now, assume $a$ is even. Then $a=2k$ for some integer $k$. Then $3a=3(2k)=2(3k)$ since $3k$ is an integer, $3a$ is even. This for the case of $a=2$ if P: $a$ is even and Q: $3a$ is even, we have $P$ and $P\implies Q$ so we get $Q$ that $6$ is even! In general $3a$ is not even, it depends on $a$!

Answer (score 2):

No, we shouldn't.  Note that $P \implies Q$ does **not** imply $Q$ is true, unless we know that $P$ is true.

Maybe an example will help.

$P$: Socrates is a man.

$Q$: Socrates is mortal.

$P \implies Q$: If Socrates is a man, then Socrates is mortal.

$P \implies Q$ is true, because it is a special case of "All men are mortal", which we assume we know. Note that 
"If Athene is a man, then Athene is mortal" is also true, even though Athene is not a man (remember that in mathematical logic, $P \implies Q$ is true when $P$ is false).

So once you establish that Socrates is a man, you have proven that Socrates is mortal.

Answer (score 1):

If $1 = 2$ then $2+2=2$, that is $(1=2)\implies(2+2 = 2)$.  It's clearly not necessary to prove $2+2=2$, which is false, to show that the above implication is true.  Instead, to prove the implication we temporarily *assume* $1=2$ and then we derive $2+2=2$ from that assumption.

Another way of looking at it is $P\implies Q$ means we can build a proof of $Q$ given a proof of $P$.  We can do this even if it turns out that there are no proofs of $P$.

Answer (score 0):

The condition $P \implies Q$ is given in the hypothesis, so you don't have to prove it.

To see this in action, let $P$ be a statement. If you show that $Q$ holds if $P$ is assumed to hold, then $P \implies Q$.

Comment: Then I guess it is a nonsense to show that Q is true given that P => Q and P are true since we first have to show that Q is true?

Answer (score 0):

> Professor says that if P => Q is true and P is true then we can say that Q is true.

That is correct. Symbolically then, you have the theorem:  $[[P \implies Q] \land P ] \implies Q$ where  '$\land$' is the AND-operator.

> I agree with the logic but how can we show that P => Q is true?

You don't need to prove it.  You begin the proof of this theorem by simply *assuming* that $[P \implies Q] \land P $ is true.

Then you can apply the Detachment Rule to infer that $Q$ is true.

Then you can conclude that $[[P \implies Q] \land P ] \implies Q$.